# How to fast switch Audio Input in AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am using AVCaptureSession to develop a camera app.

I need trigger some vibration feedback when touch some UI. using code like below:

```
private var _impact = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator()
private var _select = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()

private init() {
    _impact.prepare()
    _select.prepare()
}

func impact() {
    _impact.impactOccurred()
}

func select() {
    _select.selectionChanged()
}
```

so I can invoke `select()` or `impact()` to trigger a feedback.

But, if I add Audio Device to AVCaptureSession, all feedbacks will be invalidated. so, for the feedback effect, I have to removed AudioDevice from AVCaptureSession first, when I need to record a video, then add the Audio Device to AVCaptureSession, this operation will lag `captureOutput` that make camera preview freezed in little time.

So, I found another way to try this, first always add Audio Device to AVCaptureSession, then get all AVCaptureConnection about Audio from `AVCaptureSession.connections`. and set `isEnable` to false or true, But this way didn't work. even `AVCaptureConnection.isEnable` is false, the feedbacks also invalidate.

I think maybe there is only way to make feedback worked is don't add audio device to AVCaptureSession.

Comment: Does using two `AVCaptureSession`s help? One for audio and one for video?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I didn't try this, but should AVCaptureSession be a sington in whole application? I think.

Comment: Where does it say `AVCaptureSession` must be a singleton?